# I just made a song, its called "Ain't going there no way no how". Bards are useless cowards, how do I make them useful in combat?

Tags: combat

This guy said he was an adventurer, we paid him to help us on a mission to kill some orcs. Because screw orcs!

Turns out the guy really is just an useless bard, his sword is just for show, all he can do is sing and play a stupid small harp. Totally not worth the money, but the contract was clear....we had to pay in advance and the guy had great charisma so we couldn't refuse.

Now we are stuck with the useless idiot and we can't kill him, might as well use him to get the job done.

How can I use a bard to kill  30 orc warriors (not all at once), considering our team composed of 4 excellent fighters and a useless bard. Our plan was to just get chased by a bunch of orcs on horseback and lure them into traps but the bard is not even a skilled rider, he would just fall into the traps instead of skipping them.

Wasting money is something I hate, and I invested into that guy, might as well make an use out of him!

I need a way to give this useless bard an use in combat, what can I do?

Comment: Welcome @Sixteen. Why don't you check out the [tour](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help centre](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what questions are on-topic here. Unfortunately asking us to finish a plotline is off-topic, but if you look on RPG.SE it may be on topic there. I look forward to seeing other great questions soon eneough.

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizzaMonica This would only be on-topic on RPG.SE if it relates to a tabletop RPG campaign, and that may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: @Sixteen: Gosh that's a real shame for a beginner. You asked the same question on two different forums and they both said **question off-topic**. I think the main focus of this forum is either (a) really broad aspects of designing your plot or (c) the minutia of actually writing it. Your question is somewhere in between and the forum doesn't like it :-(

Comment: @Daron Stack Exchange is explicitly **not** a forum, it's a Q&A site.  This question is too much "what should I write" for here, and "too story-based" for [Worldbuilding.se].  As a general rule, questions are usually expected to be structured such that they might help other users who have similar issues / questions in future.